# How read'write xls and xlsx?

Tags: c#, xls, xlsx

PLease advise the library to work with these two types of.

I need one library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) works quite well in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Office.Excel or Microsoft.Office.Interop

For XSLX you can work with OpenXML but it's a lot of work. The advantage is you don't need to have Office installed for it to work.

Comment: I search a library for work